# Spring XD and Quality of Protection = privacy

Tags: kerberos, spring-xd

Does Spring XD support quality of protection = Privacy ? I have the exception below with Cloudera 5.5.2 and property set to 'hadoop.rpc.protection=privacy' .

```
2016-03-25T16:22:38+0100 WARN Spring Shell o.a.h.i.Client:673 - Couldn't setup connection for XXXX@YYYYY.LOCAL to AAAA.BBBBB.net/XX.XXX.XX.XX:8020
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: No common protection layer between client and server
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.doFinalHandshake(GssKrb5Client.java:251) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:186) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslEvaluateToken(SaslRpcClient.java:483) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:427) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:555) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:370) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:724) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:720) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:720) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:370) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1529) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1446) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getFileInfo(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771) [hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.getFileInfo(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2116) [hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305) [hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301) [hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317) [hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1655) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:326) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:235) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:218) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:201) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:165) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:287) [hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.xd.shell.hadoop.FsShellCommands.run(FsShellCommands.java:418) [spring-xd-shell-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.xd.shell.hadoop.FsShellCommands.runCommand(FsShellCommands.java:413) [spring-xd-shell-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.xd.shell.hadoop.FsShellCommands.ls(FsShellCommands.java:116) [spring-xd-shell-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) [spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.invoke(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:64) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.shell.core.SimpleExecutionStrategy.execute(SimpleExecutionStrategy.java:48) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.shell.core.AbstractShell.executeCommand(AbstractShell.java:127) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.promptLoop(JLineShell.java:533) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.shell.core.JLineShell.run(JLineShell.java:179) [spring-shell-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
```

Comment: It's been set up according to http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#_connecting_to_kerberized_hadoop and then tried to use QOP https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/sasl.html#qop

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by adding extra properties hadoop.rpc.protection=privacy to hadoop.properties in Spring XD